# Xamarin VS2022 Member not found in DataContext only at compile time

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

(Note I am commenting out everything inside the  starting from `<!--<ListView.ItemTemplate>`)

If I take out the comment block and try to run the code I get the compiler error
"

> Member not found in DataContext
> XFC0045 Binding: Property "SyllabusNumber" not found on "ViewModels.FlightViewModel"
> ".

Note: Not just SyllabusNumber, any field will fail but it only catches on the first.

If I run it with the code commented out the app will start and show me a list of object.tostring() text items "models.LessonModel".  While the app is running I then un-comment the code and use the Hot Reload and everything is working fine.

The window's DataContext is set to the ViewModel and Lessons is a public ObservableCollection in the VM. All other bindings to the VM are working fine and as expected.  I have set all access modifiers to 'public'.  I have tried it in VS2022 and VS2022 Preview.

```
                    <ListView  x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons}" Margin="30" >
                        <!--<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        --><!-- <Image Source="{Binding image}" />  --><!--

                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                            
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding SyllabusNumber}" TextColor="#ddd" BackgroundColor="#333" Padding="5,0,5,0"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#333" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            
                                            
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="#666" />
                                            
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>-->
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: Hi Ash.  That creates the error: "The property 'DataType' was not found in type 'DataTemplate'."

Comment: ASH - Totally my bad, it's a Xamarin Forms app.  Sorry about that, I have WPF and Xamarin in the same solution.

Comment: do you have a DataContext attribute elsewhere in your XAML?  Try removing it

Comment: are you including anywhere such code in this xaml. x:DataType="local:ViewModels.FlightViewModel"?

Comment: @Jason  There is the BindingContext to the Viewmodel at the top of the window: 

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:FlightViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

Comment: @AmjadS. 
This only exists at the top: 
<ContentPage 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FSM_Mobile.ViewModels"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:FSM_Mobile.ViewModels" 
             x:DataType="viewmodels:FlightViewModel"
             x:Class="FSM_Mobile.Views.FlightPage"

Comment: get rid of the `DataType` property

Comment: @Jason wins the prize    (...and again my bad if I didn't ask the question clearly)

Jason, post a full response and I'll mark it correct for you.

Comment: @RayBrennan as i asked you first , if you have this  x:DataType="viewmodels:FlightViewModel" then delete it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the `x:DataType` attribute from the XAML.  For some reason doing this for the overall page creates problems with templated controls that have their own context.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!!